# Why does my app crashes after without any error in my code?

Tags: android-studio, crash

My app crashes instantly.

Ichecked my whole code everything seems right

#### I've tried:

1. Clean project
2. Invalidate caches /restart
3. rebuilding app

here is my log:

> `2019-09-24 17:11:22.287 24723-24723/com.example.splash E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:740)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:819)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1041)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2360)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5985)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:212)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1806)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>           Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>           at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:736)
>                   ... 12 more
>   2019-09-24 17:11:22.319 24723-24723/com.example.splash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.splash, PID: 24723
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.splash.FireApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.splash.FireApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1078)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6078)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:212)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1806)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.splash.FireApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:50)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1142)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1070)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6078) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:212) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1806) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860) 
>           Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.splash-38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>           at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:736)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:819)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1041)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2360)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5985)`

Answer (score 0):

### Bad Encode

> Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.splash->38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==/base.apk': Bad `encoded_value method type size 7`

reading the log you should check if there's an array that you are missing to fill or if there is an encode problem... have you seen if all your files are encoded correctly?

if you are passing this array from other activity you should check yf both documents have the same encoding type

---

### Missing Class

> com.example.splash.`FireApp`

You can check for this to be correctly called, or may be missing on you Manifest?

---

this part of you APK its called too much times on your log

> -38vvy8h0ek5tJSz1HqPOZg==

you should check for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable proguard and is if it helps. There is an issue with proguard and AndroidX